# How pass video in kurento react native

Tags: react-native, stream, webrtc, kurento

I build streaming in mobile app. In desktop all is ok. How pass video element to kurento media server in react native ?

```
socket.onopen = () => {
    const options = {
//here is problem, because I use react-native
      remoteVideo: document.getElementById('video');,
      onicecandidate: onIceCandidate,
      mediaConstraints: { audio: false, video: true },
      configuration: {
        iceServers: [{ "urls": "turn:111.115.110.111:3118", "username": "kurento", "credential": "kure" }]
      }
    }
    webRtcPeer = new kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeerRecvonly(options,
      function (error) {
        webRtcPeer.generateOffer(onOffer);
      });
  }
```

Comment: You might want to add some code example of what you've tried and what doesn't work. Without it you make it harder for others to help you.

Comment: I think if you refer shared angular code that might help.
https://github.com/manu-cr/kurento-app/blob/master/src/services/kurento.service.ts